# Unable to save a return value from a method in Java without re-running method

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods, return-value

Brand new to coding, so sorry if this is a basic question. I'm doing an assignment to program a code for the game battleship in java.

I'm using a method to get the user to input coordinates and then save those coordinates as an array to be used in another method. I understand that a variable within a method does not save.

So I created a return for the method and then created a new variable in my main class and set to the return value of the method.

```
public static char[][] player1ships() {
  System.out.println("PLAYER 1, ENTER YOUR SHIPS' COORDINATES.");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char[][] player1 = new char[5][5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      player1[i][j] = '-';
    }
  }
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ) {
    System.out.println("Enter location for ship " + i);
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();
    if ((a >= 0 && a < 5) && (b >= 0 && b < 5) && (player1[a][b] == '-')) {
      player1[a][b] = '@';
      i++;
    } else if ((a >= 0 && a < 5) && (a >= 0 && b < 5) && (player1[a][b] == '@'))
      System.out.println("You can't place two or more ships on the same location");
    else if ((a < 0 || a >= 5) || (b < 0 || b >= 5))
      System.out.println("You can't place ships outside the " + 5 + " by " + 5 + " grid");
  }
  return player1;
}
```

I want to run the method so the user enters the coordinates and then save the return array to use later. However, When I run the program it seems to run the method twice as the the output prompts the user through 2 cycles of "enter location".

When I added the test line at the end, it does print the correct symbol at the index array so it does seem to save the updated arary.

So how do I save the return as a variable without running and printing the whole method again?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [][] strike = player1ships();
                
        
        player1ships();

        
        //test to see if array updated
        System.out.println(strike[0][0]);
        
    }
}
```

This is the result of the program running...and going through the player1ships method twice instead of once.

[showing how it prompts user through two cycles before printing out the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilHy4.png)

Comment: "it seems to run the method twice", yes, in the `main()` you call the method twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main method removing/commenting the second method call and re run the code.It working fine

```
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [][] strike = player1ships();
                
        
        player1ships();     ----> this line

        
        //test to see if array updated
        System.out.println(strike[0][0]);
        
    }
}
```

Hope its working fine?

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't complain if you call a method but do nothing with its return value, so you invoke the method `player1ships()` actually twice:

```java
char [][] strike = player1ships();
```

and

```java
player1ships();
```

You can simply remove the second call of `player1ships()` (the one without assignment) as you don't use its result.

Comment: I do want to use the return value in a different method later on though. 

I’d like to use the return value in another method that would take those values. Method is Battle(strike). Using the variable strike which is supposed to be set to the return variable from Player1ships(). But when it inputs strike, it reruns the player1ships() method again instead of using the return value.

Comment: The value will be stored in strike itself while calling it for the first time you can pass it for other method if you want.  Or can you please provide more information

Comment: @Arun yes, that is my goal is to save the return value in strike. When I try to call it in another method, Battle(strike), it still reruns the first method player1ships().

Comment: No @SarahParker it won't call the player1Ships again. I Just now tested with the same code. remove the second player1ships() method. Its working fine. Can u run again after removing the second call.If still issue can you share the full code.

Comment: You can write like this where no need to create another variable and store value. `Battle(player1ships());`

Comment: @VinitMore I think this confuses OP even more. @SarahParker can you please add a code snippet of your call to `Battle(strike)` (with a bit more context) to your question?

Comment: @arun I reran the code and you are correct, everything compiles and runs. Thank you.

Comment: @SarahParker happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. I removed the second player1ships(); method in my main method and the code worked great and also saved the variable appropriately for use in another method. I'm sure my formatting is horrible and there is a better way to write this program, but I really appreciate all the help troubleshooting!

Here is my updated code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [][] strike = player1ships();
    
    char [][] boardhit1 = battle(strike);
    
    
    //test to see if array updated
    System.out.println(strike[0][0]);
    System.out.println(boardhit1[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [][] strike = player1ships();

     //This line runs the method again, which is what you don't want.
     //player1ships();

    //test to see if array updated
    System.out.println(strike[0][0]);

}
```